# Getting desired number of terms in the Taylor series in Wolfram Alpha

Tags: wolfram-alpha

I want a desired number of terms in the Taylor series expansion of a function. How can I write the query for this? Presently whenever I write it, it stops after a few number of terms.

For example, here is the expansion for `sin x`:

[image: formula]

How to specify we want more terms than this?

P.S. [The actual query](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin+x).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to enter the query in a slightly modified form, which will accept a specific number of terms.

For example:

```
Series[Sin[x], {x, 0, 11}]
```

will produce the output

[image: Taylor series to the 11th power]

The final number within the query represents the n<sup>th</sup> power of the expansion.

Another example - A screengrab of a different number of terms:

[image: Full Entry and Output to 9th power]